# Javascript: var is equal to function which same var is passed into

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Question: Can someone explain what is happening here?

**The var root is set where it calls a function (classes), but when that function is defined it is passing in the root object.** This is what I don't understand.

Some extra details:

Because of the words I would enter into a search engine, I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. Just giving me the name of what this is called is what I'm looking for, so I can further research it.

I have just learned about recursion.

This code is not mine, it's from [here.](https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/0d81ccfd24578d5d563c55e785b3b40a) It is running fine on my local server.

```
<center></center>

<script>

var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var bubble = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("center").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = d3.hierarchy(classes(data))
      .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  bubble(root);
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.children)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
        return color(d.data.packageName); 
      });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
      console.log([classes]);
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

Comment: _“but when that function is defined it is passing in the root object”_ - no, it simply has a _parameter_ that is named `root`. This has nothing to do with the `root` variable outside of the function. You could rename the function parameter `foobar` ( `function classes(foobar)` and inside `recurse(null, foobar);`), and things would still work exactly the same.

Comment: @CBroe Correct! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The var root is set where it calls a function (classes), but when that function is defined it is passing in the root object.

No, it simply has a *parameter* that is named `root`. This has nothing to do with the `root` variable outside of the function.

You could rename the function parameter for example `foobar` (`function classes(foobar)`, and inside `recurse(null, foobar);`), and things would still work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is completely understandable, considering there are two uses of `root`, and they don't refer to the same thing.

Note that `classes` is invoked by `classes(data)`, so the `root` in the `classes` function refers to the data loaded in `flare.json`, while the `root` in your data loading function is a d3 object, returned by [`d3.hierarchy`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy).

I would recommend renaming the `root` parameter in `classes` so there's less confusion.